# Using the same UDP port for unicast receive, multicast send

Tags: windows, udp, boost-asio, bind, multicast

I've developed a simple app under Windows 10 that listens for UDP datagrams on a given port and than route the datagrams to a multicast group that uses the same port (e.g.: binds on port `0.0.0.0:5202` and sends to multicast group `224.0.0.100:5202`). This is required because the data source, originally sending in multicast may be attached to a network that does not support multicast. The application adapts the unicast communication to multicast. To avoid changes in the multicast recipients and minimize changes in the sender, we decided to leave the port unchanged (both in source and final destination).

The problem is that once I start the adapter application, the multicast recipients running in the same host fails to bind to the multicast group. I'm using boost asio library to have the application running both under Windows 10 and Linux target.

I set the reuse address socket option but the clients fails to bind in any case. Any idea ? or this thing just can't work under Windows 10 ?

Comment: Your app and the multicast receiving apps needs to use SO_REUSEPORT.

Answer (score 0):

Can the multicast recipient application listening on the loopback interface 127.0.0.1 ? If so, your adapter can listen on a physical interface (instead of 0.0.0.0), get the UDP data then resend to 224.0.0.100:5202 through interface 127.0.0.1.